# How to config CSLA for n-Tier deployment scenarios?

Tags: deployment, n-tier-architecture, csla

Need

1. Quick and fast list of configuration changes required while moving from single-tier to multi-tier in CSLA deployment
2. Detailed explanation of the above checklist
3. A How to list

Comment: Have you tried the CSLA book?

Comment: Yes Mitch. It is more of how to develop. I need how to deploy.

Comment: perhaps you should alter your question to reflect your requirements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on many scenarios like what version of CSLA you are using and also your requirements. I would start by reading up on the RunLocal attribute.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))